# What's a good Javascript tutorial library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for something that will allow me to walk a new user through a a web app one step at a time with different hints on what to click and look at. Does something like this exist?

Comment: While I'm remembering the good one I used before, here's another: [Amberjack](http://amberjack.org/)

Comment: Here's another, but it costs $9: http://revaxarts-themes.com/tour/

Comment: StackOverflow is [not a recommendation engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562). :-) Your question is off-topic here; this isn't a discussion site, I'm afraid.

Comment: This seems like an answer to me.

Comment: Good to know, but not exactly fitting that. I'm not looking for the *best*, or a recommendation. I'm contemplating if I should write this myself or if something like this exists. I can modify my question if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [jQuery Tour](https://github.com/nickrouty/jQuery-Tour) before and found it pretty good. (It's not the same as the one I commented with, by the way.) But it's true, this question isn't constructive :)

Comment: thanks @minitech for actually being helpful :)

Comment: @saji89: That's incorrect grammar. Please don't do that.